# I have json object with contain a list of other object and want to convert it in HashMap in java

Tags: java

this is the json , I wanted to convert to HashMap 
`

```
      ob = "{
         "arrival": "RONGO",
         "segmentPrices": [
          {
          "id": "",
          "localId": "",
          "localCode": "",
           "localDesignation": "",
           "amounts": [
            {
             "value": 950,
             "currency": "Ksh"
            }
               ]
            }
           ]
          } ";     

Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(gson.toJson(ob), HashMap.class);
```

`
but i can't access to amounts object,
the value of result.get("amounts") is null

somebody can please help me for this ?

Comment: What version do you use for gson?

Answer (score 1):

Using gson 2.0 here is what you can parse your json as HashMap and access amounts array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("test.json"), HashMap.class);

    ArrayList<Object> prices = (ArrayList<Object>) map.get("segmentPrices");

    prices.forEach(p -> {

        if (p instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            System.out.println(((LinkedHashMap)p).get("amounts"));
        }

    });
}
```

test.json file contains your json.

Output is:

```
[{value=950.0, currency=Ksh}]
```

You can access the parameters inside the object in the amount array as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("test.json"), HashMap.class);

    ArrayList<Object> prices = (ArrayList<Object>) map.get("segmentPrices");

    prices.forEach(p -> {

        if (p instanceof LinkedHashMap) {

            ArrayList<Object> amounts = (ArrayList<Object>) (((LinkedHashMap)p).get("amounts"));

            amounts.forEach(amount -> {
                System.out.println(((HashMap<String,Object>)amount).get("value"));
            });
        }

    });
}
```

output is :

```
950.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need the java-son library, if you need to extract the value of value this is how you can do it.

```
String ob = "{\n"
                    + "         \"arrival\": \"RONGO\",\n"
                    + "         \"segmentPrices\": [\n"
                    + "          {\n"
                    + "          \"id\": \"\",\n"
                    + "          \"localId\": \"\",\n"
                    + "          \"localCode\": \"\",\n"
                    + "           \"localDesignation\": \"\",\n"
                    + "           \"amounts\": [\n"
                    + "            {\n"
                    + "             \"value\": 950,\n"
                    + "             \"currency\": \"Ksh\"\n"
                    + "            }\n"
                    + "               ]\n"
                    + "            }\n"
                    + "           ]\n"
                    + "          } ";
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(ob.toString());

            System.out.println(json.getJSONArray("segmentPrices").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("amounts").getJSONObject(0).get("value"));
```